# Why GetDC function does not works?

Tags: api, winapi, win32gui

I am creating a game with the Win32 API and tried to draw a button by myself with this following code:

```
HWND button = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW, 100, 100, 250, 40, hwnd, NULL, instance, NULL);
HDC dc = GetWindowDC(button);
TextOut(dc, 10, 10, "test", 5);
ReleaseDC(button, dc);
```

**I want to clarify for everyone that I have tried for many situations and various functions, like FillRect, MoveTo, DrawText ...** The point is it works in WM_CTLCOLORBTN, where I get the HDC of the button with wParam. I don't understand why it doesn't work. Maybe the GetDC function is buggy? Which function should I use? **I specify that I tried with other functions like GetDC or BeginPaint/EndPaint.** What I need to do??

Comment: Follow official tutorials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program

Comment: @SimonMourier That tutorial doesn't appear to cover user-drawn buttons

Comment: Maybe the GetDC function is buggy? - Consider. Over 30 years old function and buggy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style, you need to handle (and perform drawing in) the [`WM_DRAWITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-drawitem) message in the parent window's windproc.  This is explicitly stated in the [Button Styles documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles):

> `BS_OWNERDRAW`
> Creates an owner-drawn button. The owner window receives a `WM_DRAWITEM` message when a visual aspect of the button has changed. Do not combine the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style with any other button styles.

The `lParam` of the [`WM_DRAWITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-drawitem) message is a pointer to a [`DRAWITEMSTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-drawitemstruct) struct, which contains the `HDC` you must use for drawing, among other things.

> `hDC`
> A handle to a device context; this device context **must** be used when performing drawing operations on the control.